# How I can add new field into "Customizable Options" of product's edit form in magento 2?

Tags: product, magento2

How I can add new field into "Customizable Options" of product's edit form in magento 2 programmatically?

like this
[image]

Comment: did you get any solution ?

Comment: hi. yes i have a solution. But this is a complex solution with solving some magento2's  problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert into method **getSelectTypeGridConfig** of **/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/CustomOptions.php**

```
'parent_options' => $this->getParentOptionsConfig(51, ['fit' => true]),
'parent_option_values' => $this->getParentOptionsValueConfig(52, ['fit' => true]),
```

Like it is in the picture

[image]